# Open interpretation of logical theories

Tags: logic, model-theory

This may be more appropriate for MO but I thought I'd ask here first as it's just a question about logic (not my strong point at all but not research-level in itself). I'm going through Razborov's [flag algebra](https://www.math.ias.edu/csdm/files/05-06/arazborov_flag_algebras.pdf) paper (properly [this time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015017/use-of-model-theory-in-flag-algebras)) and I'm struggling with what an *open interpretation* of logical theories *actually is*. It's defined on p.14 as follows:

> Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be two universal first order theories in respective languages $L_1$, $L_2$ which do not contain function symbols (they can contain predicate symbols and constants). Let $U(x)$ be an open formula in $L_2$ such that $T_2 \vdash U(c)$ for every constant $c\in L_2$. Let $I$ be a *translation* which sends each predicate symbol $P(x_1, \dots, x_r)\in L_1$ to an open formula $I(P)(x_1, \dots, x_r)\in L_2$ and each constant $c\in L_1$ to a constant $I(c) \in L_2$. Extend $I$ to open formulas in $L_1$ by declaring it commutes with logical connectives. The pair $(U, I)$ is called an **open interpretation** of $T_1$ in $T_2$ if for every axiom $\forall x_1, \dots, x_r A(x_1, \dots, x_r) $ of $T_1$, we have
>   $$T_2 \vdash \forall x_1, \dots, x_r \left[\left(U(x_1)\wedge \dots \wedge U(x_r) \right)\implies I(A) (x_1, \dots, x_r) \right]$$

So the interpretation of every axiom (in this case some formula consisting of relations and constants) of $T_1$ is an open formula in $T_2$ and it is provable in $T_2$ that $U(x_1)\wedge \dots \wedge U(x_r)$ implies $I(A)(x_1, \dots, x_r)$ for any $x_1, \dots, x_r$.

I cannot get my head around this, although I follow the logical terminology. How do people think of such interpretations? Can I roughly think of this as "$U$ implies the interpretations of the axioms of $T_1$, giving an "interpreted" copy of $T_1$ living inside $T_2$"?

Comment: We can say that the "predicate" $U(x)$ restricts the domain $D$ of the interpetation (i.e. the "universe" in which individual variables and quantifiers range) to the "subset" $U^D$ containing only those elements of $D$ such that $U(x)$ holds of them.

Comment: A silly example : consider a theory about the domain $P$ of $Philosophers$ and some axiom like $\forall x Bald(x)$, stating that (in the "intended" interpretation) : "all philosophers are bald". We can "restrict" this theory to the sub-domain of Greek philosophers with a suitable predicate $Greek(x)$ and rewrite the axiom as follows : $\forall x (Greek(x) \to Bald(x))$.

Comment: A silly but excellent example! This has really helped me. So for instance if my domain is "graphs" (an application of flag algebras) with an axiom "$\forall x T(x)$ with the interpretation "$x$ contains a triangle", then we can restrict to the sub-domain of graphs containing a 4-cycle with the predicate $C_4 (x)$ for "$x$ contains a 4-cycle". So in this restricted domain if a graph contains a 4-cycle it also contains a triangle. Right?

Comment: More or less ... With non-silly examples, we have to prove the "interpretability". I mean : if $\forall x T(x)$ is an axiom (a "good" one) we expect that it is true, and this means that "every graph contains a triangle". If so, obviously also "a graph with a $4$-cycle contains a triangle". What we need is to "map" the theory $T_1$ into $T_2$ with a suitable $U(x)$ such that for any axiom $\forall x \phi(x)$ of $T_1$ we are able to prove in $T_2$ that the "interpreted" axiom holds, i.e. that $T_2 \vdash \forall x [U(x) \to \phi^*(x)]$.

Comment: Okay, this is starting to make a lot of sense! Of course, I should perhaps have set my domain as "graphs containing a triangle" but regardless I'm beginning to see how this works and how it can be used to force combinatorial structures to have certain properties. Thanks so much!

Comment: The answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090437/how-to-prove-that-gödels-incompleteness-theorems-apply-to-zfc may also be of interest.

Comment: @RobArthan thanks for this link, this is also very helpful!